# Convert This Array of Objects into Normal Array For Month User Count In Apexchart

Tags: php, laravel

```
[{
    "January": 0,
    "February": 0,
    "March": 0,
    "April": 0,
    "May": 1342.58,
    "June": 0,
    "July": 0,
    "August": 0,
    "September": 0,
    "October": 0,
    "November": 0,
    "December": 0
}]
```

Above is an array of objects I want it to convert like:-

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1342.58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
```

Below is my Controller Code:-

```
  public function dashboardView(Request $request){
        $data = CustomerTransaction::SELECT(DB::raw("SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 1 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 2 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 3 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 4 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 5 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 6 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 7 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 8 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 9 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 10 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 11 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
        SUM(CASE MONTH(created_at) WHEN 12 THEN total_price ELSE 0 END) AS 'December'"))->get();      
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: A better approach might be to let the database do that repetitive work for you by selecting ```MONTH(created_at), SUM(total_price)``` and ```GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)```.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extract the values from the first row of the data to remove the keys...

```php
return array_values($data[0]);
```

The `array_values()` will force the conversion of the object `$data[0]` into an array then extract the values into an array.